# wait() function for azure nodejs sdk

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-node-sdk

Is there a wait() function available for azure nodejs SDK just like what python SDK has.
Below is my python code to start a VM in azure

```
async_vm_start = compute_client.virtual_machines.start(group_name, vm_name)
async_vm_start.wait()
```

So here my whole program waits till the VM completely spins up and proceeds.
Below is my nodejs code to start a VM

```
clientCompute.virtualMachines.start(resourceGroupName, vmName, function(err, result) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(result);
})
```

Here my program don't wait and just proceeds further even though behind the scenes the VM is still in the process of starting.

I have tried setTimeout but it's not reliable. So is there any way for my nodejs function to wait till the VM completely start.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument to the `start()` function is a callback function which will be called after the VM has been started. If you had the following code:

```
console.log('I will be logged first!')
clientCompute.virtualMachines.start(resourceGroupName, vmName, function(err, result) {
    console.log('I will be logged after the VM has started!')
})
console.log('I will be logged almost immediately after the first!')
```

you would see the order that they will run. If there is anything that needs to happen *after* the VM has started, do it inside of that callback.

Of course, it can be a pain if you have many things to do in order and you have a callback inside of a callback inside of a callback...it just gets messy. I'm not sure what version of the SDK you are using but with newer ones you could use async/await:

```
console.log('I will be logged first!')
await clientCompute.virtualMachines.start(resourceGroupName, vmName)
console.log('I will be logged after the VM has started!')
```

or use promisify to convert callback-based functions into promises which can be awaited.